# Regular expression to match French and German characters 

Tags: java, regex

I am parsing the request parameters to find any vulnerable characters to prevent XSS threats. Our web application supports both French and German languages other than English. I am using the following regular expression to achieve this, but it fails to handle French and German

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\r\n\\-=\\*\\.\\?;,+\\/:&_ %@#]*$
```

Any suggestions on this is highly appreciated

Comment: Which regex variant are you using: Perl, Python, .NET, or something else? (The solution will be related to Unicode character classes, but the details depend on the regex implementation.)

Answer (score 10):

[`\p{L}` will match any unicode character that is a letter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: It also matches Asian letters.

Comment: But doesn't match accented letters. \p{M} is for character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Try `[\p{Latin}\p{Punctuation}\p{Math_Symbol}]` or add more character classes. Have a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for other unicode character classes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question.

But hope it helps someone out there! you can try this regex:

`([\u0020-\u007e\u00a0-\u00ff\u0100-\u017F]+)`

Basically it should match all the Latin and extended Latin characters, including numbers, feel free to remove the unicode characters as necessary. I would say that this would be the surest way of getting it right for all your scenarios.

References:

- http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf
- http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf
- http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf