# How to match only words using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

This is a two-fold question.
1. How to incorporate foreign characters implicitly?
2. How to get rid of the ending empty string?

```
IEnumerable<String> words = Regex.Split(input, "[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+");
```

The above worked like a charm. Then the Germans came along and started complaining that some of their words got split in half. That occurs when the string contains dotted or accented characters. One way to tackle it is to add more characters to the pattern but then we have the French, Polish and basically **any** non-english language (only latin characters are valid).

**What would be a better way to patternize *all characters and digits and the dash*?**

When I played with different strings, I also noticed that if there's a question mark at the end, I get an empty string as the last split part. I'm simply checking if the last element is en empty string and cut it off, right now.

**Why do I get it and how do I get rid of it?**

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727081/regular-expression-to-match-french-and-german-characters

Comment: @GuyL. Probably not a duplicate, asks about .NET regex not Java, and asks about why Split generates an empty entry for this specific code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Regex + Linq?

```
IEnumerable<String> words = Regex.Split(input, @"[^\w0-9-]+")
                                 .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
```

A non-regex solution is also possible

```
var words = new string(input.Select(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c=='-' ? c : ' ').ToArray())
            .Split()
            .Where(s=>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

See: [MSDN: Character Classes in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx) for .NET flavour regex:

- [Word character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter) syntax is `\w` (the character classes in that table are defined at the [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/). This is *almost* the same as `a-zA-Z0-9-`, but you may need to play with things like `\p{L}0-9-` if you want to exclude underscores.

**Edit:** And, for reference, there is an article explaining why this all works (and a-zA-Z doesn't) [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

**You also asked** How to get rid of the ending empty string?

`String.Split` gives you the option of getting rid of the empty entries, `Regex.Split` doesn't. Your empty entry is coming due to you using the `?` as a split point as you are identifying non-word characters to use for splitting. You have two simple options:

- test for an empty entry in your IEnumerable
- update your regex so it won't match your last non-word character

But, if you do the second option, you will end up with that last character (your `?`) included in your last IEnumerable entry. So, the first option is better, unless you want to change the way you are doing this to use positive matching to pull out continuous words, such as:

```
MatchCollection m = new Regex("\\w+").Matches(input);
List<string> words = new List<string>();
foreach (Match item in m)
{
    words.Add(item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET, this will only match words (even if they are double quoted or pre/postfixed with non-alphanumeric characters.

Regex(@"[^0-9-!$%^&@#*()_+|~ =`{}[]:;'<>?,./""""""]\w+")

Will match the text in the variable txt:

```
var txt = "000 fred is just \"mad:)\"."
```

with:
**["fred"; "is"; "just"; "mad"]**